# Find the number of positive real values of $a$, such that $a^2 x^2 + ax - 1 + 7a^2$ has $2$ distinct integer roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

**Problem** Find the number of positive real values of $a$ for which the given equation has 2 distinct integer roots.

$$ a^2 x^2 + ax - 1 + 7a^2 $$

Till now, I have the following inferences. Assuming $\alpha, \beta$ to be the roots, we have

$$\alpha + \beta = \frac{-1}{a}$$
$$\alpha\beta = -\frac{1}{a^2} + 7$$

But since $\alpha, \beta$ are integers, this implies that $|a| \leq 1$. Also by the quadratic formula, we have

$\alpha = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{28a^2 - 3}}{2a}$

From here we can infer that since the requirement is just integer roots, if $a$ satisfies the condition, then $-a$ also satisfies the condition. Thus, we may find the total number of solutions and divide by two to get the number of positive integers. However, whether this is helpful or not, I can not figure. One trivial solution emerges, i.e. $a = \pm 1$. I cannot make progress beyond this.

Comment: Do you require the $a$ of your starting polynomial to be an integer, or only the roots of the polynomial?

Comment: $a$ should be real, I have edited the question.

Comment: $a=-1/\gamma$, where $\gamma=\alpha+\beta$ is a positive integer. From there, perhaps you can get to $28-3\gamma^2$ being a perfect square, which should narrow things down.

Comment: Check your formula for $\alpha\beta$ again.  It should be $7-\frac1{a^2}$ instead of $\frac1{a^2}-7$ for your quadratic.

Comment: Now that error propagates to your formula for $\alpha$, hence also to what @GerryMyerson suggested.

Comment: Maybe the given equation is supposed to be : $a^2x^2+a x =-1+7a^2$ in which case you do have three solutions $a=1,1/2,1/3$

Comment: Certainly the way the problem has been posted, $a=\pm1$ leads to $x^2\pm x+6=0$, which has no integer roots (in fact, no real roots). This supports the suggestion of user @Loz.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP is not responding.

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to respond. There was an error in the source where I encountered the problem, and the intended problem appears to be the correction @Lozenges has suggested.

Comment: Then please edit your question to be what you think it was intended to be, Shivansh. Users should not have to wade through a long comment stream in order to understand the question.

Comment: In order to prove that a second-degree equation has two different roots, isn't it the simplest way checking the discriminant?

Answer (score 1):

$$a^2x^2+ax+(7a^2-1)=0$$

Let $m,n$ be integer roots of the quadratic . Then, you have :

$$
\begin{align}m+n&=-\frac 1a, \thinspace a≠0\\
mn&=7-\left(\frac {1}{a}\right)^2\end{align}
$$

This leads to :

$$
\begin{align}(m+n)^2+mn&=7\\
m^2+3mn+(n^2-7)&=0\end{align}
$$

Thus, we can assume that :

$$\Delta_m=5m^2+28=k^2, \thinspace k\in\mathbb Z$$

Working with $\color{#c00}{\rm{mod}\;5}$, we have $k=5p+q$ , where $1≤q≤4$, which yields $5\mid q^2-3$ . A contradiction .

Therefore, no solution exists .

Comment: The answer given for the problem was 3.

Comment: @ShivanshJaiswal Well, then let's wait for feedback from mathematicians.  Unfortunately, I'm not an expert ..

Comment: I think the answer given is wrong, your answer seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is wrong according to your answer that is 3 , this question has been taken from **16-th All-Russian Mathematical Olympiad 1990** round 4 grade 9 P5 .

The original question is    Find all positive values of a for which both roots of the equation **($a^2$)($x^2$) + ax + 1 -7($a^2$)=0** are integer . So I will answer according to the original question .

Rearrange the equation by taking quadratic in *a* (Treat *x* as constant instead of *a*)

so *($a^2$)[$x^2$ - 7] + ax + 1 =0*

as both *a* and *x* are integer therefore D = k^2    (for any integer k)

so $x^2$ -4($x^2$ - 7)*1 =$k^2$

= 28 - 3$x^2$ = $k^2$

clearly only x = -1,-2,-3,1,2,3 satisfy the condition

Now we have to check by placing the possible values of *x* in quadratic formula if *a* is also an integer or not .

checking it we will find it that (*a,b*) = (-1,2) ,(-1,3),(1,-2) satisfy .